# Click a button with XPath containing partial id and title in Selenium IDE

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-ide

Using Selenium IDE, I'm trying to click a button within a table on a webpage using XPath with a partial id and a title from the element. The XPath I'm using is:

```
xpath=//*[contains(@id, 'ctl00_btnAircraftMapCell')]//*[contains(@title, 'Select Seat')]
```

and thats the entire html code for an example of the buttons im trying to click:

```
<li id="ctl00_MainContent_repAircraftMap_ctl20_repAircraftMapRow‌​_ctl00_liAircraftMap‌​Cell" class=""> 
    <a id="ctl00_MainContent_repAircraftMap_ctl20_repAircraftMapRow‌​_ctl00_btnAircraftMa‌​pCell" href="javascript:void(0)" seatnumber="20A" mapbindattribute="1124" title="Select Seat 20A" onclick="SeatClick(1124);"></a> 
</li>
```

Am I constructing this incorrectly? It's not working!

Comment: share the HTML of that button

Comment: If you can format code here, and take reasonable care with writing questions to be as readable as possible, the effort is often appreciated.

Comment: <li id="ctl00_MainContent_repAircraftMap_ctl20_repAircraftMapRow_ctl00_liAircraftMapCell" class="">
<a id="ctl00_MainContent_repAircraftMap_ctl20_repAircraftMapRow_ctl00_btnAircraftMapCell" href="javascript:void(0)" seatnumber="20A" mapbindattribute="1124" title="Select Seat 20A" onclick="SeatClick(1124);"></a>
</li>

Comment: thats the entire html code for an example of the buttons im trying to click - Thanks, Mike

Comment: good point about being a readable Q! - what i should say is that when i execute a 'click' or 'clickAt' command with the above xpath - the response is 'not found'

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Now that you have provided your HTML sample, we're able to see that your XPath is slightly wrong. While it's valid XPath, it's *logically* wrong.

You've got:

```
//*[contains(@id, 'ctl00_btnAircraftMapCell')]//*[contains(@title, 'Select Seat')]
```

Which translates into:

Get me *all* the elements that have an `ID` that contains `ctl00_btnAircraftMapCell`. Out of these elements, get *any* child elements that have a `title` that contains `Select Seat`.

What you *actually* want is:

```
//a[contains(@id, 'ctl00_btnAircraftMapCell') and contains(@title, 'Select Seat')]
```

Which translates into:

Get me *all* the **anchor** elements that have **both**: an `id` that contains `ctl00_btnAircraftMapCell` and a `title` that contains `Select Seat`.

Comment: This is quite possibly the best explained answer on stack overflow! I never knew you could use "and" like you have done in an xpath expression, thanks for that