# selenium webdriver find element in region

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Working with automated testing, I have come across the following issue quite a lot of time: I want to find an element on the page, but the element has to be at a specific region of the page.

Take the following as an example:
I have a searchfield with type-ahead on the site. In my sidebar, I have the element I am seraching for (lets call it "Selenium"), but that is not the element I am interested in, I want to see if my type-ahead search is delivering the expected result when searching for "Selenium".

```
<body>
   <header>
      <searchfield>
         <searchresults>
            <a .... >Selenium</a>
         <searchresults>
      </searchfield>
   </header>
   <aside>
      ...
      <a .... >Selenium</a>
      ...
   </aside>
</body>
```

If I in selenium webdriver search for the linktext "Selenium" it will find both entries, the one in the sidebar aswell as the one in the searchfield.
Furthermore am I not able to wait for the searchresult with the `WaitForVisible` command on the linkText as Selenium will find the element in the sidebar and conclude that the element is preset.

So my question is:
"With selenium webdriver, how do I search for an element within a specific region?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poking around with this issue, I came across the use of Xpath. With this I could create "areas" where I want to search for an element. As an example, I went from

```
html/body/div/aside/div[2]/ul/li
```

to

```
//div[contains(@class,'coworkerwidget')]/ul/li
```

Now the code is MUCH more dynamic, and less prone to errors if our frontend guys edit something in the future.

Regarding the search, I could now set up something like the following code

```
//div[contains(@class, 'searchfield')]//div[contains(@title, 'searchfield') and contains(., '" + searchword + "')]"
```

First we specify that we want to look in the searchfield area:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'searchfield')]
```

I can then set some more criteria for the result I want to find:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'title') and contains(., '" + searchword + "')]
```

Some litterature on the subjects for further reading.

http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=388

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

[Click a button with XPath containing partial id and title in Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930683/click-a-button-with-xpath-containing-partial-id-and-title-in-selenium-ide)

[Retrieve an xpath text contains using text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570857/retrieve-an-xpath-text-contains-using-text)