# Selenium code doesn't click the respective object in the application

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

```html
<div id=":tabs-innerCt" data-ref="innerCt" role="presentation" class="x-box-inner x-box-menu-body-horizontal" style="width: 217px; height: 30px;">
<div id=":tabs-targetEl" data-ref="targetEl" class="x-box-target" role="presentation" style="width: 181px;">
<a 
class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small gw-top-menu-selected" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" id="TabBar:AdminTab" tabindex="-1" componentid="TabBar:AdminTab" style="right: auto; top: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px;">
<span id="TabBar:AdminTab-btnWrap" data-ref="btnWrap" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small x-btn-split x-btn-split-right">
<span id="TabBar:AdminTab-btnEl" data-ref="btnEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small x-btn-text    x-btn-button-center ">
<span id="TabBar:AdminTab-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small  " style="">
</span>
<span id="TabBar:AdminTab-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small">Adminis<span class="g-underlined">t</span>ration</span>

</span>
</span>
</a>
```

I am new in Selenium. I was trying to automate a scenario in the application.
I found a difficulty in executing a script. I have coded as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("TabBar:AdminTab-btnInnerEl")).click();
```

However this object is not identified during execution.

Could you please help me in this regard. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Okay. I thought it will be easier. Here is the code. <span id="TabBar:AdminTab-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small">Adminis<span class="g-underlined" id="ext-element-86">t</span>ration</span>

Comment: Instead of publishing the updates as comments edit the main question with this information for further analysis.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? If your locator (By.id) is the wrong ou should get ElementNotFound exception. However if you don't get any exceptions but your click does not work as you expect this could be because there are several elements matching your locator or the click is performed too fast (untill the page is properly loaded)

Answer (score 0):

It could be because id you are looking for contains ':' symbol. Try

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
By locator = By.xpath("//span[contains(@id, 'AdminTab-btnInnerEl') and contains(@text, 'Adminis')]"));
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator);
element.click();
```

I found these useful:

[Click a button with XPath containing partial id and title in Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930683/click-a-button-with-xpath-containing-partial-id-and-title-in-selenium-ide)

[elementToBeClickable condition](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is not working. There are 4 different IDs for the same  Tab. 2 Tabs for Admininstration and 2 tabs for the drop.down. Either I get Element not found or Element is not interactable.

Comment: @PrakashS updated my answer with a xPath query that will take element with id containing "AdminTab-btnInnerEl" and text containing "Adminis". Yep this is quite ugly and not very much save from ui changes but still might be useful to solve your particular case

Comment: I again got an error message: "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(@id, 'AdminTab-btnInnerEl') and contains(@text, 'Adminis')]"}". Looks like this is complex.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, it works. I have given  Thread.sleep(5000); Looks like it needs some time to load the page. Thanks for your support.    Thread.sleep(5000);
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='TabBar:AdminTab-btnInnerEl']")).click();
                  Thread.sleep(5000);

Comment: @PrakashS sleeps are ok for a quick resolution but they are not robust enough. I updated my answer with a preferred solution using waits. If it works for you please mark the answer as 'accepted' so others can see that is helped to solve your case